# Google Cloud SQL -- Accessing GCS bucket resources directly from PL/pgSQL COPY statement

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, plpgsql, google-cloud-sql

So I have a Cloud SQL instance that has the following PL/pgSQL statements imported into it:

`\COPY db_table_1 FROM 'bucket/data1.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t';
\COPY db_table_2 FROM 'bucket/data2.tsv' DELIMITER  E'\t';`

I'm just trying to figure out how to format the path to access the data.tsv files. I've tried formatting like `gs://bucket/resource` but that doesn't work either. Is there a resource on GCP that I missed that explains how to access different resources directly from another resource?

I feel like this is either an issue of me not understanding the file system that GCP runs on, or maybe accessing different resources in this way is just not possible without some API call.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Have you looked at `gcloud sql instances import`?

Comment: @Vadim Yep. I'm making a workaround now by automatically creating insert statements from the .tsv lines